# An extension to assign colors to new tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: chrome

Is there any extension for Google Chrome that can change the colors of the background of the tab labels in the tab list?

When you open 20 tabs, you want to find certain tabs very quick, without searching them. So you need to paint certain tabs in distinct colors, so you can find them quick.

The label (the element in the tabs list that shows the tab name) is always painted in white background, it would be wonderful to be able to change this color.

Comment: There is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-colorizer-customize-y/nkdjooaecafkkldnkaokhpaindamlngj/related?hl=en which changes the favicon to a coloured block, which will probably be fine for use case :)